Clone a 24.04 install to another similar machine
I have Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04 installed on a Z97 Motherboard.
Just Cloned it with a duplicator dock.
Installed it on another Z97 machine.
The source machine has no GPU.
The destination machine has a GTX 960 GPU.
Having problems with no access to the repository.
Can access the rest of the internet OK.
Below is the error message that I am getting.
The installation could have failed because of an error in the corresponding software package or it was cancelled in an unfriendly way. You have to repair this before you can install or remove any further software.
Transaction failed: Previous installation hasn't been completed
E:Method http has died unexpectedly!, E:Sub-process http returned an error code (100), E:Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly

Try the following:
Open a terminal
Run in it
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt -m install
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean

